# How to traverse next/Previous 3 element in a list using Jquery each() method

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, responsive-slides

I have a list items something like this that has images inisde it

```
 <li class="fluidratio" id="transparent-btns1_s1" style="display: list-item; transition: opacity 500ms ease-in-out 0s; float: none; position: absolute; opacity: 0; z-index: 1;">
        <div class="bg pg target thumbnail">
            <img class="thumb big" src="http://images01.inmotico.com/318/642/3186422000RC/580X420/679b12140b5450eeade90df9b0dc0a2d.JPG" name="secondary" style="margin-top: -19.5px;">
        </div>
        <div class=" pagination_img">2 de 12</div>
    </li>
  <li class="fluidratio" id="transparent-btns1_s1" style="display: list-item; transition: opacity 500ms ease-in-out 0s; float: none; position: absolute; opacity: 0; z-index: 1;">
        <div class="bg pg target thumbnail">
            <img class="thumb big" src="http://images01.inmotico.com/318/642/3186422000RC/580X420/679b12140b5450eeade90df9b0dc0a2d.JPG" name="secondary" style="margin-top: -19.5px;">
        </div>
        <div class=" pagination_img">2 de 12</div>
    </li>
  <li class="fluidratio" id="transparent-btns1_s1" style="display: list-item; transition: opacity 500ms ease-in-out 0s; float: none; position: absolute; opacity: 0; z-index: 1;">
        <div class="bg pg target thumbnail">
            <img class="thumb big" src="http://images01.inmotico.com/318/642/3186422000RC/580X420/679b12140b5450eeade90df9b0dc0a2d.JPG" name="secondary" style="margin-top: -19.5px;">
        </div>
        <div class=" pagination_img">2 de 12</div>
    </li>
  <li class="fluidratio" id="transparent-btns1_s1" style="display: list-item; transition: opacity 500ms ease-in-out 0s; float: none; position: absolute; opacity: 0; z-index: 1;">
        <div class="bg pg target thumbnail">
            <img class="thumb big" data-src="http://images01.inmotico.com/318/642/3186422000RC/580X420/679b12140b5450eeade90df9b0dc0a2d.JPG" name="secondary" style="margin-top: -19.5px;">
        </div>
        <div class=" pagination_img">2 de 12</div>
    </li>
```

After 3rd list element I am adding the url for images in `data-src` tag .

In the fiddle you can see two button to move next or previous image .
So I want to check the Next or Previous 3 images if it has attribut data-src I want to change it to src .If not then do nothing and check the next one .

Here is the working fiddle for it .

[**LinkForFIddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Vicky_Anand/UvL7N/17/)

If not this method then I am open for any other solution like . Maybe with ajax if I can do that

**UPDATE**

Here is Another link . In this example I am able to change all the data-src to src once the button is clicked . But I am trying to change only next 3 consecutive images 
[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Vicky_Anand/UvL7N/18/)
Thanks & Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting the next 3 consecutive images means that **a simple `slice` is not sufficient, because you can reach the end of the image list**. The following example should demonstrate this issue:

```
var imgs = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], // every number stands for an image
    currentIndex = 3;

// For getting the next three images a simple slice is not enough:
var result = imgs.slice(currentIndex+1, currentIndex+1+3);
console.log(result); // result is [4, 5]
```

So at the border of an array you need **a combination of two calls of the function `slice`**.
A jQuery solution for your problem could then be coded like this:

```
/**
 * Find the previous elements and jump to the beginning of the list, if no more
 * elements are available at the right side of the list
 * 
 * @param  {Object} $elements A jQuery object with the elements
 * @param  {Number} index     The current index
 * @param  {Number} num       The number of elements to return
 *
 * @return {Object}           A jQuery object with the found elements
 */
function next($elements, index, num) {
    // first try to slice enough elements (a maximum of num) 
    // of the right side of the index
    var $found = $elements.slice(index+1, index+1+num),
        diff = num - $found.length;

    // if there are not enough elements make a second slice 
    // at the beginning of the array
    if(diff) {
        $found = $found.add($elements.slice(0, diff));
    }
    return $found;
};

/**
 * Find the previous elements and jump to the end of the list, if no more
 * elements are available at the left side of the list
 * 
 * @param  {Object} $elements A jQuery object with the elements
 * @param  {Number} index     The current index
 * @param  {Number} num       The number of elements to return
 *
 * @return {Object}           A jQuery object with the found elements
 */
function prev($elements, index, num) {
    // first try to slice enough elements (a maximum of num) 
    // of the left side of the index
    var $found = $elements.slice(Math.max(index-num, 0), Math.max(index, 0)),
        diff = num - $found.length;

    // if there are not enough elements make a second slice 
    // at the end of the array
    if(diff) {
        $found = $found.add($elements.slice($elements.length - diff));
    }
    return $found;
};

/**
 * A helper function for choosing between next and prev 
 * on the basis of the direction
 * 
 * @param  {Object} $elements A jQuery object with the elements
 * @param  {Number} index     The current index
 * @param  {Number} num       The number of elements to return
 * @param  {Number} direction The direction to search for elements
 *                            1 stands for forwards and -1 for backwards
 *
 * @return {Object}           A jQuery object with the found elements
 */
function nextOrPrev($elements, index, steps, direction) {
    var func = direction === 1 ? next : prev;
    return func($elements, index, steps);
}
```

To get this working with your example **you must keep track of the current index and the direction**. Since you are using the plugin `responsiveSlides` you can do this like this:

```
var lastIndex = 0,
    index = 0,
    direction = 1,
    $lis = $(".rslides li"),
    len = $lis.length;

$("#slider1").responsiveSlides({
    startidx: 0,
    auto: false,
    pager: true,
    nav: true,
    speed: 500,
    maxwidth: 540,
    namespace: "transparent-btns",
    before: function(i) {
        // there is a bug that the index is sometimes -1, here is the fix:
        if(i < 0) {
            i = len + i;
        }
        lastIndex = index;
        index = i;
        direction = (lastIndex+1)%len === index ? 1 : -1;
    }
});
```

The last thing you have to do is to **replace the line**

```
$lis.each(function(i, n) {
```

**with this line**:

```
nextOrPrev($lis, lastIndex, limit, direction).each(function(i, n) {
```

Here is the complete **[jsfiddle-example](http://jsfiddle.net/UvL7N/24/)**

Comment: thank you for the elaborated answer . I learned a lot from this answer especially the concept behind it .

Comment: But if you test your answer for number of <li> more than 4 it doesnot work . Looks like it runs till 4 images and then stop. WHat I mean to say If I click next button then the next function is being called only 2ice after that its not being called . So only 4 images are being loaded

Comment: I checked the problem you mentioned and updated the answer. Now it should work also with more than 4 images.